# Heroku: Fail to connect to database externaly using metabase

Tags: postgresql, heroku, metabase

I'm trying to use metabase to connect my Heroku app database. And it failed, give the return

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myuseraccount"
```

the screenshot look like this

[image]

The info I eneter is found through the interface of Heroku web dashoboard,

[image]

My question is that, how can I debug for this problem? There are several possibilities that I'm looking into, for example:

1. The heroku disabled connect to free-plan database externally
2. The metabase fail to connect, or I get the pw wrong

However, from the [doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress) I'm reading, seems like neither is the case. so I don't have too much clue on what to do right now.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to postgres automatic maintenance system in heroku, in Hobby-dev plan.
I belive that your application was deployed in heroku as metabase application.
So, you can change the credentials everytime you want. So do this:
Run

```
heroku pg:credentials:url -a app_name;
```

Copy this credentials settings and paste in metabase database settings.
The credentials settings is the heroku application, not the metabase application.
Even the both are deployed in heroku. 
I had the same problem and the only way which I could fix was getting my credentials by this way.
I hope this helps you.